# How do I install Kinetic from a DVD?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, offline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to install Kinetic Kame on a system with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but the catch is the only way I can put something on the system is via DVD (no Internet or USB drives).

So my question is, is there a way that I can neatly pack what I need onto a DVD for installation? I have read on Ubuntu's site that I can use Keryx, Synaptic (which I think needs a USB device), or apt-offline to install packages on non-networked computers.

Does anyone have any experience installing ROS using one of these options? Is one more preferable than the other for ROS, especially for a DVD installation? I'm open to hearing other methods as well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296864/how-do-i-install-kinetic-from-a-dvd?/) by [anonymous36363](https://answers.ros.org/users/36363/anonymous36363/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2018-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I install some software offline in this way but i don't test it with ros, for this way  we have two pc A with internet and B no internet the source of ubuntu installation on both computer must be same.

1_install ros on A

2_go to /var/cache/apt/archives

3_ copy all pkg

4_paste to another computer with same directory

5_update your pkg in B

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2018-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0